# How to covert oracle clob column to list using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, cx-oracle

I'm trying to read a clob column from oracle table into a pandas dataframe. I need to convert the pandas dataframe before I pass it to a classifier as list.

The result shows -
  with multiple entries

I want to see a result like ['string1', string2','string3']

Please help
Code snippet below -

```
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle
connection = cx_Oracle.connect('username/pass@localhost/schema')
statement = "select clob_column from table "
df = pd.read_sql(statement, con=connection)
#print(df.head())
corpus=(df['CLOB_COLUMN'].values.tolist())
print (corpus)
```

Comment: What does *The result shows - with multiple entries* mean?: please post what is `df.head()` and what is expected output

Comment: Please see [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], and [mcve].

Comment: the result of df.head() is - 
   CLOB_COLUMN
0 string1
1 string2
2 String3


    The result as of now shows multiple entries like <cx_Oracle.LOB object at 0x00000227A605B390>, <cx_Oracle.LOB object at 0x00000227A605B3C0>,

     Expected result is  ['string1', string2','string3']

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve your problem using the following approach:

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd

connection_string = 'username/pass@localhost/schema'
clob_column_name = 'CLOB_COLUMN'
query = "SELECT {} FROM table".format(clob_column_name)

with cx_Oracle.connect(connection_string) as connection:
    df = pd.read_sql(sql=query, 
                     con=connection)
    # need to read data from cx_Oracle.LOB objects
    df[clob_column_name] = df[clob_column_name].apply(lambda x: x.read())

print(df[clob_column_name].values.tolist())

# ['string1', 'string2', 'string3']
```

Comment: The right answer. Thanks!

Comment: This is too slow in my case. Is there a faster solution?